# Verification on Intersection of Tangent Lines.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Given a function $\gamma (t) = (-1,4)(2-3t)^2 + (1,0)(3t - 1)^2 $ figure out the control point $P1$ which exist at the intersection of the tangent lines of $P0$ = $\gamma (0) $ and $P2$ = $\gamma (1) $.

I'm a little rusty with intersections using the tangent lines, so any clarification/ correction would be appreciated.

I got $P1 = (1/3, -112)$ which seems odd cause -112 is really far off for a control point for such a parabola.

EDIT: figured it out I'm an idiot $P1=(0, -8)$

Comment: Not even close, as you suspected. How did you calculate this? Are you studying Bézier curves? If so, then you're probably not supposed to construct the tangents and intersect them.

Comment: $P1 =(0,-8)$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: convert the equation to Bézier form. Then the middle control point is the intersection of the two end tangents.